# Auto text wrap for webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I am facing the same problem as other developers for wrapping text vertically in WebView. I already checked and tried some hints given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835754/how-to-make-text-fit-to-screen-text-wrap-in-webview-with-kitkat) .

The below image is nothing but a webview with a long text(html) which is showing vertically. I want to show it horizontaly in multi lines.

I also got some clue that we can solve this by using some javascript in webview, but still not able to do it. I still don't know what and where to write javascript code and how to push it to the html/webview so it can show the text in a proper multiline format.

The question has asked multiple times but still there is no proper answer for this unfortunately.

My current code is like below:

```
    getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // I think you will need this one
    getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);// no need I think

    getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

And populating the data in webview something like (here descView is the WebView):

```
List<Element> elements = htmlObj.getElements();
         if( elements.size() > 0 &&  elements.get(0).getHtml() != null && !elements.get(0).getHtml().equals("")) {
             String htmlWrapper = null;
                if(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getApplication() == null) {
                    htmlWrapper = CoreSettings.HTML_WRAPPER;
                } else {
                    Application application = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getApplication();
                    htmlWrapper = application.getGlobalStyle().getHtmlWrapper();                    
                }   
             if(htmlWrapper != null) {
                    descView.loadData(htmlWrapper.replace("{{content}}",WebUtils.linkifyHtml(  elements.get(0).getHtml())), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                } else {
                    descView.loadData(WebUtils.linkifyHtml( elements.get(0).getHtml()).toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                }
         }
```

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835754/how-to-make-text-fit-to-screen-text-wrap-in-webview-with-kitkat

Comment: try getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately both solutions I have tried, but not helping

Comment: Try setting  android:vmSafeMode="true" in your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: @Tasneem Where to write and how it helps me ?

Comment: It is basically to disable ART ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler, but it helped me once in this scenario also. So just try.

Comment: tried, but no change. Thanks for the new idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

Use `WideViewport` and `Zoom out` if there is no `viewPort` defined.

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
```

Comment: Its not helping unfortunately