# How to upload HtmlLink to Android WebView

Tags: java, webview

I'm trying to uplaod html link url to Android Webview.

But I've noticed that it is differ by Android device and OS version.

In Some Device shows the whole texts while the other does not show all the texts.

Is there any way to show whole texts Programmatically.

I'm using Java language and the code is Just

```
this.loadUrl(strHtml);// this load www.blahblah.com/blah.html
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835754/how-to-make-text-fit-to-screen-text-wrap-in-webview-with-kitkat

Comment: @Monster Brain,  Thanks you're my Life Saver.

The Right Answer was this line :
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);

Comment: you're welcome ..